# How do I log into phpMyAdmin after receiving this error... #2003 Cannot log in to the MySQL server

Tags: linux, phpmyadmin

I am installing phpMyAdmin on a CentOs server and I have installed it successfully, from what I can tell. I can at least travel to the index page where it asks for my username and password. When I try to log in with any combination of default usernames and passwords, I receive this error **#2003 Cannot log in to the MySQL server**.

I followed this guide (http://www.krizna.com/centos/how-install-phpmyadmin-centos-6/) to help me install phpMyAdmin. From researching this, I am under the impression that after you log in with the default username:root and password:null, you will be able to change the username and password. I tried changing the config.inc.php value AllowNoPassword to TRUE, but that also didn't seem to help. How do I set a username and password so I can successfully log into phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue. Only some of the required software was installed on the server when I was assigned to the project. After installing mysql-server, I was able to change the root password for mysql. I changed the config file for phpmyadmin to receive the log in data through html not cookies or config. Everything works great now, I hope this helps at least one other individual.